# How can I type the "isomorphic","not equal" and "the set of integers , rationals and reals" symbol?

Tags: support, mathjax

How can I type the "isomorphic","not equal" and "the set of integers , rationals and reals"  symbol ?

What is the code ?

$=$ means equal, how to write "not equal"

What about real numbers, rationals, natural numbers and integers?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`$\cong$` for $\cong$

`$\ne$` for $\ne$

`$\mathbb{R}$`, `$\mathbb{Q}$`, and `$\mathbb{Z}$` for $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathbb{Z}$, respectfully.

See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to do it all.

Comment: thanx :) what about the symbol of generated group ?

Comment: @MathsLover That's something you will find by following the link in the answer, or the links given there. Or from  the source code of posts on the main site, which you can see by clicking `edit`.

Comment: ok :) i will explore :D

Comment: respectfully. ;-)

Answer (score 45):

One method for finding the LaTeX for a character is to draw it on
http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

You can practice all the symbols here

http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php